# Python 3 datetime.fromtimestamp fails by 1 microsecond

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, unix-timestamp, python-3.4

I want to save datetimes with microsecond resolution as timestamps. But it seems that Python 3 datetime module lost one microsecond when loading them. To test this let's create a script:

**test_datetime.py**:

```
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

for n in range(1000):
    d = datetime(year=now.year, month=now.month, day=now.day,
            hour=now.hour, minute=now.minute, second=now.second,
            microsecond=randint(0,999999))

    ts = d.timestamp()
    d2 = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)

    assert d == d2, 'failed in pass {}: {} != {}'.format(n, d, d2)
```

**python3 test_datetime.py** always fails by one microsecond:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_datetime.py", line 14, in <module>
    assert d == d2, 'failed in pass {}: {} != {}'.format(n, d, d2)
AssertionError: failed in pass 4: 2014-07-02 11:51:46.984716 != 2014-07-02 11:51:46.984715
```

Is this behavior to be accepted? Shouldn't we rely on datetime.fromtimestamp if we want microsecond resolution?

Comment: Slightly easier method of generating a new value with new microsecond value: `d = now.replace(microsecond=randint(0,999999))`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yeah, thanks. I just wanted to be very explicit in the question.

Comment: I would find `now.replace(microsend=randint(0,99999))` *clearer* as you then don't have to parse through the other 6 keyword arguments to see what you are doing in that line.

Answer (score 4):

Timestamp values are *floating point values*. Floating point values are *approximations*, and as such, rounding errors apply.

A float value of `1404313854.442585` is not precise, for example. It is really:

```
>>> dt = datetime(2014, 7, 2, 16, 10, 54, 442585)
>>> dt.timestamp()
1404313854.442585
>>> format(dt.timestamp(), '.20f')
'1404313854.44258499145507812500'
```

That's awfully close to 442585, but *not quite*. It is **just below** 442585, so when you take *just* the decimal portion, multiply that by 1 million, then take just the integer portion the 0.991455078125 remainder is ignored and you end up with 442584.

As such, when you then convert the floating point value back to a `datetime` object, 1 microsecond rounding errors *are normal*.

If you require precision, don't rely on `float`; perhaps instead store the microsecond value as a separate integer, then use `dt.fromtimestamp(seconds).replace(microsecond=microseconds)`.

You may find the [rejection notice](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-February/116837.html) to [PEP-410 (*Use decimal.Decimal type for timestamps*)](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0410/) enlightening in this context. The PEP touched upon the precision issue with timestamps represented as floats.

Comment: Doesn't this indicate a flaw in `fromtimestamp` in that it truncates instead of rounding? Given that the timestamp is *expected* to be slightly off. This suggests a work-around by using `fromtimestamp(ts + 0.0000005)`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: [This patch](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/180e4b678003/) introduced the parameter; before that the rounding was implicit in other operations. According to the comments and the [issue introducing it](http://bugs.python.org/20530) the old rounding behaviour was preserved here, with explicit rounding introduced for problems elsewhere.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Ah, found it. See [this issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue14180); rounding was changed because that's the more common behaviour elsewhere and avoids rounding a timestamp *into the future*.

Comment: @MarkRansom: e.g. rather have half the timestamps be one microsecond behind than have another half be one microsecond into the future.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the reasoning in that issue. There's an important principle I like to adhere to: when there are complimentary functions, the round-trip should always yield identical results, if possible. And in this case it *is* possible. Even just adding a `nextafter` rather than rounding would fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A timestamp is a POSIX time, which is essentially conceptualized as an integer number of seconds since an arbitrary "epoch". `datetime.fromtimestamp()` returns "the local date and time corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, such as is returned by `time.time()`" whose [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) tells us it "Return[s] the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number. Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second."

Expecting six decimal digits of precision to be retained through a conversion to and back from a timestamp seems a little unreasonable when the intermediate data type doesn't in fact guarantee sub-second accuracy. Floating point numbers are unable to represent all decimal values exactly.

**EDIT:** The following code tests which microsecond values are invalid for an arbitrary datetime when the program is run.

```
from datetime import datetime
baset = datetime.now()

dodgy = []
for i in range(1000000):
    d = baset.replace(microsecond=i)
    ts = d.timestamp()
    if d != datetime.fromtimestamp(ts):
        dodgy.append(i)
print(len(dodgy))
```

I got 499,968 "dodgy" times, but I haven't examined them.

Comment: `datetime` doesn't actually use `time.time()` though, microseconds are supported regardless of platform. This *is* however, an issue with floating point numbers.

Comment: I'd agree it's a floating point issue, and hadn't realized that all platforms now provide microsecond accuracy - merely that they report the timer to best resolution _as_ a floating point number.

Comment: *499,968 "dodgy" times*: almost half. And that sounds correct, because the [C code rounds down](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/34ec73494e74/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#l4130) (note the `_PyTime_ROUND_DOWN` constant there) when converting. Given 1 million floating point values, chances are a little less than half will be off slightly below the original microsecond value, and another almost-half just above. The remainder are values that could be represented as a binary fraction exactly.